# If $P/I_kP$ are finitely-generated, is it true that $P/IP$ is finitely-generated where $I=\bigcap I_k$?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, projective-module

I'm looking into some old results on "big projectives'', and trying to understand some steps.

Assume that $R$ is a (commutative) ring and $I_1,\ldots,I_n$ are ideals. Let $I=I_1\cap\cdots\cap I_n$ be their intersection. Finally suppose that $P$ is a module such that $P/I_kP = P\otimes R/I_k$ is finitely-generated for all $k$ (as an $R$-module or $R/I_k$-module, it doesn't matter).

Is it true that $P/IP$ is finitely-generated?

---

Here's a case where I can work it out: if the $I_k$'s were pairwise comaximal, then $R/I = \bigoplus R/I_k$ by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, so $P/IP = \bigoplus_{k=1}^n P/I_kP$ is certainly finitely-generated. In general I'm not sure how to write down a surjection from $\bigoplus_{k=1}^n P/I_kP$ to $P/IP$.

---

Here is some extra context I have in my case:

- $P$ is projective
- $R$ is noetherian
- $I_1,\ldots,I_n$ are the minimal primes over zero (by Noether's Theorem)

I suspect none of these additional assumptions are necessary, and that what I asked is true in general. Unless minimal primes are always pairwise comaximal, but I'm unaware of that ...

Comment: Hint towards a proof in the general case (sorry if it's wrong -- I don't have much time to check right now): It suffices to prove that if $I$ and $J$ are two ideals of $R$ such that $P/IP$ and $P/JP$ are finitely-generated $R$-modules, then $P/\left(I\cap J\right)P$ is a finitely-generated $R$-module (your statement then follows by induction). So, consider such $I$ and $J$. It suffices to check that $P/IJP$ is a finitely-generated $R$-module (since $P/\left(I\cap J\right)P$ is clearly a quotient of $P/IJP$). In order to do so, it is ...

Comment: ... enough to check that $JP/IJP$ and $P/JP$ are finitely-generated $R$-modules (since $P/IJP$ fits in a short exact sequence between these two). For $P/JP$, this is clear by assumption. For $JP/IJP$, on the other hand... OK, this is where my argument fails. If $J$ is finitely-generated, then $JP/IJP$ would be generated by the products of the generators of $J$ with the generators of $P/IP$. In the general case, this might not be finitely-generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution when $R$ is noetherian. Since all the $P/I_kP$'s are finitely-generated, so is their sum $\bigoplus P/I_kP$. This is finitely-generated over a noetherian ring, hence noetherian, so all of its submodules are finitely-generated. But we can view $P/IP$ as a submodule via $x+IP\mapsto (x+I_1P,\ldots,x+I_nP)$.